# IIS listening 127.0.0.1 instead 0.0.0.0

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, tcp, bindings

I configure binding on my IIS 7 server like:

```
ip address: All Unassigned
port: 8080
```

but in `netstat -aon` command see only `127.0.0.1:8080` instead `0.0.0.0:8080`(which I would like)

(`0.0.0.0:8080` is free (there is not it in netstat table))

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all. Problem is solved.

I use command:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

and saw `127.0.0.1` in listening list. (But I didn't add it manually). So I delete it and add `0.0.0.0` instead.

```
netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

Then I restarted iis server.